# Экспорт DataTable в Excel из ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

за пример взял эту тему [форум асп.нет](https://forums.asp.net/t/2066840.aspx?Best%20way%20to%20export%20data%20from%20a%20Datatable%20to%20Excel%20using%20C%20)
Использую следующий подход

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("SampleColumn", typeof(string));
            // Add Three rows with those columns filled in the DataTable.
            table.Rows.Add("0");
            table.Rows.Add("1");
            table.Rows.Add("2");
            table.Rows.Add("3");
            table.Rows.Add("1");
            table.Rows.Add("2");
            table.Rows.Add("3");


            ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook wbook = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook();
            wbook.Worksheets.Add(table, "tab1");
            // Prepare the response
            HttpResponse httpResponse = Response;
            httpResponse.Clear();
            httpResponse.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            //Provide you file name here
            httpResponse.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"Samplefile.xlsx\"");

            // Flush the workbook to the Response.OutputStream
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.WriteTo(httpResponse.OutputStream);
                memoryStream.Close();
            }

            httpResponse.End();
```

Пробовал код как в контроллере, так и в отдельном классе, но при использовании строчки `HttpResponse httpResponse = Response;`
В VisualStudio ошибка "Имя "Response" не существует в текущем контексте". Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код в примере - из метода контроллера. У базового контроллера есть свойство `Response`. Передавайте `Response` из контролера в этот код.

Comment: Спасибо. Но есть нюанс свойство Response есть, но если даже просто в методе контроллера прописать HttpResponse httpResponse = Response;, то сообщает ошибку "Не удаётся неявно преобразовать тип System.Web.HttpResponseBase в System.Web.HttpResponse"

Comment: @АлександрЩучко Объявите `HttpResponseBase httpResponse = ...`

Comment: Действительно. Работает как надо.

Comment: @АлександрЩучко Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Текущий контекст http всегда содержит ответ. Находится он тут

```
 HttpResponse httpResponse=System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
```